# Yii Rights :: Not able to access controller action with defined Roles

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have successfully install Yii-Rights modules with Yii-Users.

I have:-

1. Create a Roles (Authenticated)
2. Give permission to certain controller.action (Campaign.index)

However, when i login to the system as "Authenticated" roles, (I'm sure rights is working fine in the login, since i redirect the user by the roles), the Campaign.index return Error 403 -> You are not authorized to perform this action.

However when "Admin" roles go into the controller it working just fine. I noticed there is a way to allow the user to enter the controller, with allowedaction(), but when i logout and enter the function, it displays. So, It is not a solution.

In my Controller, i have

```
class CampaignController extends RController {

/**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout = '//client/dashboard';

/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters() {
    return array(
        'rights', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            //'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions' => array('index', 'view', 'create', 'update'),
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions' => array('admin', 'delete'),
            'users' => array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

I have read most of the web regarding to this topic, but i found none that have the same problem like i do. I have tried uninstall the module, and install back but no luck.

Im using Yii 1.1.14 and the latest Yii-rights downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-rights/ (Last updated 2014-02-20)

Please help me define my problems.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Try to add 'accessRules' to the array in function filters()

Comment: Okay, i found a solution. It is because my controller is inside a folder. For example protected/controller/client/CampaignController.php. I need to provide my folder name inside the Permission for example: client/Campaign.index to make it works. Anyway, after 2 days finding a solution, it really worth it. :)